# Passing java attribute to a javascript function array argument

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, arrays

Currently, I have a servlet that forwards to a jsp. The jsp has access to a session attribute "current".
During the loading of the jsp, the information in "current" is passed to a javascript function that generates a graph.
This is all working fine. My only problem is that i'm hard coding the graph data.

How would i go about passing the data array from the servlet to the jsp. Basically, in the creerRapport function, in the 5th argument,
how do I replace that with java attributes?

Any help or ideas would be appreciated.

**My current code with hard coded data.**

```
<body onload="soumettreRapport();">
<script type="text/javascript">
    function soumettreRapport() {

        creerRapport( "${current.title}",
                      "${current.type}",                                    
                       ${current.width},
                       ${current.height}, 
            [ 
             {
               key: "Cumulative Return",
               values: [
                 { 
                   "label" : "2001" ,
                   "value" : -29.76
                 } , 
                 { 
                   "label" : "2002" , 
                   "value" : 0
                 } , 
                 { 
                   "label" : "2003 , 
                   "value" : 32.80
                 }
               ]
             }
           ]
        );
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Servlet, You need to to have JSON array as String then put this String into Request scope.

```
String jsonArrayString = convert(...); // Output [{key:"Cumulative Return", .... }]

request.setAttribute("jsonArrayString", jsonArrayString);
```

In JSP:

```
function soumettreRapport() {

    var jsonArray = ${jsonArrayString};

    creerRapport( "${current.title}",
                  "${current.type}",                                    
                   ${current.width},
                   ${current.height}, jsonArray );

}
```